# can't insert data into table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have created table using this command successfully

```
create  table Person(
  first_name varchar(25) not null,
  last_name varchar(25) not null,
  persoin_id number not null, 
  birth_date date,  
  country varchar (25),
  salary  number);
```

and now I want to insert data into that table

```
insert into  Person(persoin_id,first_name,last_name,salary,birth_date,country)
 values(100,'dato','datuashvili',350,to_date('01/01/10','DD/MM/YY'),'georgia');
 values(101,'irakli','oqruashvili',350,to_date('01/03/10','DD/MM/YY'),'georgia');
```

first row is inserted,but problem is with second  line

```
1 rows inserted.
```

> Error starting at line 10 in command:
>   values(101,'irakli','oqruashvili',350,to_date('01/03/10','DD/MM/YY'),'georgia')
>   Error report:
>   Unknown Command

Please help me to determine what is problem?thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on a RDBMS that supports multi-rows inserts in one `INSERT`:

```
insert into  Person(persoin_id,first_name,last_name,salary,birth_date,country)
   values
 (100,'dato','datuashvili',350,to_date('01/01/10','DD/MM/YY'),'georgia') , 
                                                       --- comma here ---^
 (101,'irakli','oqruashvili',350,to_date('01/03/10','DD/MM/YY'),'georgia') ;
 ^--- no "values" here
```

---

If not (like Oracle), you'll have to issue two insert statements:

```
insert into  Person(persoin_id,first_name,last_name,salary,birth_date,country)
   values
 (100,'dato','datuashvili',350,to_date('01/01/10','DD/MM/YY'),'georgia') ;
                                                  --- as it was  here ---^

insert into  Person(persoin_id,first_name,last_name,salary,birth_date,country)
   values
 (101,'irakli','oqruashvili',350,to_date('01/03/10','DD/MM/YY'),'georgia') ;
```

or use this approach:

```
insert into  Person(persoin_id,first_name,last_name,salary,birth_date,country)
   select
 (100,'dato','datuashvili',350,to_date('01/01/10','DD/MM/YY'),'georgia') 
       from dual
   union all select
 (101,'irakli','oqruashvili',350,to_date('01/03/10','DD/MM/YY'),'georgia') 
       from dual
 ;
```

Comment: yes thanks,but i have one question,it repeats    inserting into many rows,just  copying,how to stop it?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have a program that calls repeatedly this `insert` ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use 2 insert statement instead of one for 2 different sets of data...

```
insert into  Person(persoin_id,first_name,last_name,salary,birth_date,country)
  values(100,'dato','datuashvili',350,to_date('01/01/10','DD/MM/YY'),'georgia');

insert into  Person(persoin_id,first_name,last_name,salary,birth_date,country)
  values(101,'irakli','oqruashvili',350,to_date('01/03/10','DD/MM/YY'),'georgia')
```

Comment: You can do that. But you don't need to. You can have 2 (or more) rows inserted in one `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @ypercube: that depends on the DBMS that is used. With Oracle this is not possible (and looking at the create table statement, this is most probably Oracle)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, you are right, the error message is from Oracle probably. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `;` at the end of:

```
values(100,'dato','datuashvili',350,to_date('01/01/10','DD/MM/YY'),'georgia');
                                                                             ^
```

change it to `,` and also loose the `values` from the next line. You need just one `values` per insert.